# Vue Router - missing param for named route eror

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My id is being successfully transferred to my URL but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I tried a method where I added a default params to my `path: '*'` but to no avail.

[image]

**routes.js**

```js
{
  path: '/objective/employee/:id',
  name: 'employee-objective',
  component: () => import('@/views/EmployeeObjective'),
  meta: { requiresAuth: true }
},
```

**Component**

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <p class="display-2 text-center">DASHBOARD</p>
    <p class="overline text-center">Current route is still under construction</p>

    <template v-for="employee in employees" >
      <v-row :key="employee.id">
        <v-col ><router-link :to="{ name: 'employee-objective', params: { id: employee.id }}">{{ employee.first_name }}</router-link></v-col>
      </v-row>
    </template>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: ()=> ({
      employees: []
    }),

    created () {
      this.employeeList ()
    },

    methods: {
      employeeList () {
        axios
        .get('/api/employees')
        .then(response => this.employees = response.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have now found the culprit. In my `App.vue` I have a navigation drawer that also has a router link to `employee-objective` without the `params: { id: }` now I have to figure out how to get the authenticated user id to be passed on the `params: { id: //auth::user->id }`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `employee` data is missing an `id` field.

Check these examples:

- With `id` your example works as expected: [employee with id](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-with-id-5q7d3)
- Without `id` you will see `[vue-router] missing param for named route "employee-objective" in console: Expected "id" to be defined`: [employee without id](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-without-id-28rjz)

Comment: I do have the id field in the database. But your codepen was amazing, I'll try to discover other things that are affecting the application with the help of your provided code.